# removing decimal places in a data with spaces in-between numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, decimal

got the following code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1=pd.read_excel('FA9th june.xlsx')
df1.head()
    Days    Amount  Repayments  Balance
40.0    19 500.00   15 000.00   4 500.00
40.0    19 500.00   0           19 500.00
40.0    9 750.00    2 670.00    7 080.00
40.0    32 500.00   11 500.00   21 000.00
40.0    3 250.00    580         2 670.00
```

I want my data to  be without them spaces in between number and without the decimal places, looking like this:

```
    Days    Amount  Repayments  Balance
   40       19500   15000       4500
   40       19500   0           19500
   40       9750    2670        7080
   40       32500   11500      21000
   40       3250    580         2670
```

I tried converting it to int but it kept returning this error:

```
 invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19 500.00'
```

whenever I run this code:

```
df1['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(X['Amount'], errors='ignore').astype(int)
```

Comment: Already done. I have done it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need these conversions:

```
df1['Days'] = df1['Days'].astype(int)
df1['Amount'] = df1['Amount'].map(lambda x: x.replace(' ','')).astype(float).astype(int)
df1['Repayments'] = df1['Repayments'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.replace(' ','')).astype(float).astype(int)
df1['Balance'] = df1['Balance'].map(lambda x: x.replace(' ','')).astype(float).astype(int)
```

which give:

```
   Days  Amount  Repayments  Balance
0    40   19500       15000     4500
1    40   19500           0    19500
2    40    9750        2670     7080
3    40   32500       11500    21000
4    40    3250         580     2670
```

The `Days` column is easy: just convert it to `int`.
For the other columns you need to convert them in `str`, if necessary as `Repayments`, then apply the `.replace(' ','')` method to remove whitespaces, then convert them in `float` and finally in `int`.
The direct conversion from `str` to `int` is not always possible, in most cases you need first go through `float` type.

Comment: this code here df1['Balance'] = df1['Balance'].map(lambda x: x.replace(' ','')).astype(float).astype(int)  returned an error, '''AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'replace''' so I added a .astype(str) before .map(lambda x: x.replace(' ','')) and it worked jus fine.

Comment: Exactly what I got with the `Repayments` column, you applied the same solution I did, good

Answer (score 3):

You can also do this:

```
df = df.replace(' |\.[0-9]*', '', regex=True).astype('int32')
```

or

```
df = df.replace(' |\.\d*', '', regex=True).astype(int)
df
```

```
   Days  Amount  Repayments  Balance
0    40   19500       15000     4500
1    40   19500           0    19500
2    40    9750        2670     7080
3    40   32500       11500    21000
4    40    3250         580     2670
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert numbers in locales where the group (thousands) separator is a space character (`1 234 456`) and the decimal point/separator is a `.` (`123.456`), you can use a regular expression to capture the number:

```
\d{1,3}( \d{3})*(\.\d+)?
```

which is to say: match 1-3 decimal digits, followed by zero or more groups consisting of a single space, followed by 3 decimal digits, with the whole followed by an optional group consisting of a single '.' followed by 1 or more decimal digits.

Once you have that, a simple replace will get rid of the group separators (' ') and the fractional part. You'll want to specify the `global` flag on the regular expression so that it will match all occurrences.